# V S code V1.31 emmet intellisense not working with Python/Django Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I installed Visual Studio Code 1.31.0 recently and also installed the python and django extensions. When I'm tying to create new HTML file, and typing "html" it was not showing with the emmet responses and after quite a bit of struggle, when I uninstalled python and django extensions, things are back to normal.

Any help on how to get emmet working with python and django extensions installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django)

as explained in the descriptionof the above link, you will have to enter the following code in your settings file.

```
"files.associations": {
"**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
"**/templates/*": "django-txt",
"**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the settings.json as below path:

> %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json

2. Edit the file as below:

> ```
> {
>   "files.associations": {
>       "**/*.html": "html",
>       "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
>       "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
>       "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
>   },
>     "workbench.editorAssociations": [
>         {
>             "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
>             "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
>         }
>     ],
>     "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>         "django-html": "html"
>     },
>     "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
>     
>         "markdown"
>     ]
>   
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

its simple just go to settings-> Emmets and in emmets you will find include library option just click on that in language write django-html and in value add html
BOOM IT IS DONE.

Answer (score 0):

On vs code, open *settings*, go to => *Extensions* => *EMMET* => scroll down and locate on the ( *INCLUDE LANGUAGES* ) => click on (*ADD ITEM* ). the first input which is the ( *KEY* ) type **django-html** and the second input which is the ( *VALUE* ), type **html**

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your Settings.json in VS Code

```js
{
  "files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it but what I find suitable is :

1. Go to settings
2. Click the icon shown in image
   [image: How to go json]
3. After you open json there is bunch of code or maybe not rest assure and go to the last of it.
4. then add one more item

   "emmet.includeLanguages" : {
   "django-html" : "html",
   }

in your json like I do in the following image

[image: adding new language to vs code via json]

Now your emmet start working again.. If not try to restart.